# How do I define an array of MPI types in C?

Tags: c, arrays, mpi, openmpi

I defined an array of size 8 and type MPI_INTEGER in C, using the code below:

```
/*=================================================================
C example 
=================================================================*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){    
    MPI_FLOAT itype[8];     
    int nproc;
    int iproc;
    MPI_Comm icomm;
    MPI_Request req;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

    icomm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    MPI_Comm_rank(icomm,&iproc);
    MPI_Comm_size(icomm,&nproc);

  itype[0]  = MPI_FLOAT;
  itype[1]  = MPI_FLOAT;
  itype[2]  = MPI_FLOAT;
  itype[3]  = MPI_FLOAT;
  itype[4]  = MPI_FLOAT;
  itype[5]  = MPI_FLOAT;
  itype[6]  = MPI_FLOAT;
  itype[7]  = MPI_UB;

    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

and I received the following errors:

```
type_derived_struct.c(18): error: expected a ";"
        MPI_FLOAT itype[8];     
                  ^

type_derived_struct.c(93): error: identifier "itype" is undefined
    itype[0]  = MPI_FLOAT;
```

I am using intel openmpi. Thank you!

Comment: I see no reference to `MPI_INTEGER` in your code.

Comment: `itype[0] = MPI_FLOAT;` looks odd.  Is `MPI_FLOAT` a type (as suggested by the array declaration) or a constant value (as suggested by the array initialisation)?

Comment: Predefined MPI data types (like `MPI_FLOAT`) are really just named constants of type `MPI_Datatype`. They cannot be used to define variables but rather the corresponding language type should be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
MPI_Datatype itype[8];
```

`MPI_Datatype` is the type of `MPI_FLOAT` (and `MPI_INT`, etc.)

Comment: Ahh, now the question makes a lot more sense.